# Integrating Google FIT API: Handling Multiple Scopes in Initial Authorization Request

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-fit, google-fit-api, google-fitness-api

I'm currently working on integrating the Google FIT API into my JavaScript application, and I'm encountering an issue when trying to include multiple scopes in the initial authorization request.

The following request works perfectly with a single scope:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?[clientID]&redirect_uri=https://health.silkland.com&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read&response_type=code&access_type=offline
```

However, when attempting to include more than one scope with a space between them, as shown below, it doesn't seem to work as expected:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?[clientID]&redirect_uri=https://health.silkland.com&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.heart_rate.read&response_type=code&access_type=offline
```

Is there a specific syntax or method I should follow to include multiple scopes in the authorization call? I appreciate any guidance or examples demonstrating the correct way to structure the request for multiple scopes. Thank you!